# python pandas merge on unique row values in a single dataframe

Tags: pandas

i have a Data Frame as below..

Name       id       Products
Rajesh    1001      Biscuits
Rajesh    1001       Soap
Ramesh    1002      Biscuits
Ramesh    1002       Soap

i need the Data Frame as below ..

Name       id       Products
Rajesh    1001     Biscuits , Soap
Ramesh    1002     Biscuits , Soap

Comment: You can group by (Name,id) then apply a custom function to concatenate the values : https://medium.com/@sean.turner026/applying-custom-functions-to-groupby-objects-in-pandas-61af58955569

Answer (score 0):

try these:

**Option 1**:

```
df.groupby(["name","id"]).agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

**Option 2**:

```
df.groupby(["name","id"]).apply(lambda x: list(x["prod"]))
```